# Accessing Properties in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

When trying to access the Companies property in the OnPost() action it is empty, but it is not in the OnGet().

I am new to Razor Pages and MVC in .net in general.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    ICompanyRepository _companyRepository;
    public CreateModel(ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
    {
        _companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Company company { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; } 

    public void OnGet()
    {
         Companies =_companyRepository.GetCompanies();            
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {       
        company.DatabaseId = Companies.Find(x => 
            x.CompanyId.Equals(company.CompanyId)).DatabaseId;

        company.Active = true;
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _companyRepository.Create(company);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Message = ex.Message;
                return Page();
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            Message = "Please complete form";        
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

I expect that i would be able to access the Companies property from any of my actions. But when i go to Find inside Companies, it is null. I am using that same list to populate a selectlist on the page as well, and the list is populated as expected. Once i go to post, it is null. I appreciate any assistance anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web is stateless. Each time a request is made to the page, whether as a result of a `get` or `post` request, the PageModel class for the page is created and its properties are set to their default values. Once it has done its job and generated the HTML to be rendered, it, and its properties are destroyed.

Currently, you only populate the `Companies` property when the request uses the `get` verb. You also need to populate the property when the verb is `post`:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    Companies =_companyRepository.GetCompanies();
    company.DatabaseId = Companies.Find(x => x.CompanyId.Equals(company.CompanyId)).DatabaseId;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike. I did not realize it worked like that. This will definitely help me moving forward.